# Prevent bootstrap 4 from adding automatically active class to a checkbox button

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

I want to create a custom angular checkbox component. My problem is, that bootstrap's JavaScript somehow automatically adds class name `active` to a button when it's pressed and keeps it there. When I click to a checkbox's label, everything works fine. The problem is only when I click to a checkbox. Can I somehow prevent this?

Here is a working [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aizo8s).

My custom component looks like this:

**checkbox.component.html**

```
<div class="checkbox btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons" (click)="onClick($event)">
<label class="checkbox-input btn btn-xs"
[ngClass]="{'btn-primary active': value, 'btn-outline-secondary': !value}">
    <input type="checkbox" [checked]="value" autocomplete="off">
    <i class="fas fa-check" [ngClass]="{'fa-invisible': !value}"></i>
</label>
<label class="checkbox-label" *ngIf="label">{{ label }}</label>
```

**checkbox.component.ts**

```
import {Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "checkbox",
    templateUrl: "./checkbox.component.html"
})
export class CheckboxComponent {

@Output()
public valueChange: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();

@Input()
public value: boolean = false;

@Input()
public label: string;

// ToDo: if the user un-selects checkbox by clicking directly on checkbox, the class "active" remains on element

public constructor() {}

public onClick(event: MouseEvent): void {

  event.preventDefault();

    this.value =! this.value;

    this.valueChange.emit(this.value);
}
```

}

Comment: You can replace [checked]="value" by [(ngModel)]="value"

Comment: you can pass `$event` in onclick and use this `data.target.classList` to get className